# Converting an ISO8601 string into DateTime format?

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I have a string `20130510T202132Z` that I want to convert into a `DateTime` object.

I've been trying to use Joda to get this to work but I can't get it to work.
I've hit every link I can find on the subject -- and used formatters but it simply isn't working out.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: In future, if you've tried things it's worth showing what you've tried and explaining how it's not worked for you.

Comment: FYI, this format with minimal use of separators is known as the [“basic” version of the ISO 8601 standard formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles). The “extended” format uses separators such as `2013-05-10T20:21:32Z `.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Joda Time makes this really easy, as it has built-in support for the ISO format:

```
DateTimeFormatter iso = ISODateTimeFormat.basicDateTimeNoMillis();
DateTime dateTime = iso.parseDateTime(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to the java.time classes.

## `DateTimeFormatter`

Unfortunately this “basic” (minimal separators) version of the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format is not predefined in java.time as of Java 8. Use [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class to specify a matching pattern.

```
String input = "20130510T202132Z";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmssX" );
```

By the way, the version with separators such as `2013-05-10T20:21:32Z` is known as the [extended version of ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles).

## `OffsetDateTime`

Parse as a [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object. This class represents a moment on the timeline adjusted to a certain [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), resolving to nanoseconds. In this case the offset is [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) itself.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse ( input , f );
```

> odt.toString(): `2013-05-10T20:21:32Z`

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).